# Using Python Image Library with VirtualEnv on Windows

Tags: python, windows, django, python-imaging-library, virtualenv

I'm attempting to install the PIL library in an Virtual Enviroment that I have created.

Usually to install PIL I'd grab the install, however this won't allow me to choose my virtualenv only my root Python folder (C:/Python26).

I tried both pip install PIL and easy_install PIP but they didn't work. I've also tried downloading the TAR, extracting and running setup.py install

Django is still rejecting my model which contains an ImageField(). Does anyone have a solution?

An error which commonly occurs is below:

```
Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

*Edit:*

OK I tried a fresh virtualenv and used easy_install which isn't showing the compile error.

I then open a Python shell and it allowed me to `import PIL` and `import _imaging`, however when I try to use the `ImageField()` in django my models still won't validate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK this appears to be a VirtualEnv problem.

Despite making a new VirtualEnv with the --no-site-packages argument, my Django site is fetching the django files from the root install `C:/Python26/Lib/site-packages/` rather than locally.

Django then attempts to fetch PIL in the root `site-packages` which it cannot find and results in an error.

I have no idea why this is occurring. If I open the python interpreter the root django files do not appear on the path.

Once remedied `easy_install PIL` should work.

Answer (score 6):

Rename from PIL-1.1.7-py2.6-win32.egg to PIL in site-packages dir.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have (the latest version of) Visual Studio installed?

That's where `vcvarsall.bat` comes from, and what building any Python extension from C sources on Windows would prefer to use (there *are* ways of using `mingw` instead, if that's your actual problem).

(I'm saying "the latest version" because I believe that's what the python.org distribution of Python 2.6 for Windows is built with).

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2010 installed, not sure were to go from here though.

Comment: @Anarchist, is the directory where that .bat lives on your PATH environment variable?

Comment: I've added it to the PATH but still it saying it cannot be found.

Comment: I think 2.6 is build with VS2008